# How to know the address of end of the heap?

Tags: c

Thanks for the replies and answers. This question was edited because it seems my whole previous questions were very blur and doesn't give the exact details of what I want to achieve and my goal.

**Updated Question:**

Using C language in Linux platform, what possible ways to determine the size of the heap used in my application. Like for example..

```
void printHeapReport( )
{
   /* implementation here to print the heap size */
}

int main()
{
    char *ptemp = NULL;
    p = (char*)malloc( 10 ); /* 10 bytes */

    printHeapReport();

    return 0;
}
```

The application will output in the standard output screen:

```
Debug Report:  
--------------  
Heap: 10 bytes  
--------------
```

I ask this because I want to create a debug report in application that will print the size of the heap.

Please advice.

Many thanks.

---

**Old Question:**

Using C asm inline function, is it possible to know the address of the start of the heap and the end of the heap? Also the address of the end of the program?

```
asm( <assembly code> );
```

So that using this code I can determine the size of the heap used in my application. Is this approach is valid to determine the size of the heap?

Please advice.

Many thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by "the end of the program"? End of code section? Or end of the last section? Or end of the assembler procedure?

Comment: Hi Max, I mean of code section. Thanks

Comment: I'd be impressed if you could tell me a good reason to need to do this.

Comment: Hi GMan, I really need to calculate the size of the heap. Is it my approach is logical to get the heap size of my application?

Comment: You can't calculate the size of the heap using the address of the end of code section.

Comment: What do you need to know the size of the heap for? And what does "heap" mean to you? On some systems, there is a `mallinfo` function which reports stats from `malloc`; it's usually defined in the nonstandard `malloc.h`. This might serve your needs.

Comment: @Max: Thanks, is there a standard way without using the asm to calculate the size of the heap? Thanks
@R: Thanks I'll try to look that.

Comment: @sasayins: So why do you need the "size", if there is such a thing?

Comment: @GMan: I want to implement a basic debug report everytime my application execute if the debug mode is enabled. Thanks

Comment: @sasa: That doesn't answer the question. Is your answer "because my report prints the size of the heap"? Or is it "because I want to use that information in some sort of calculation"? There's numerous things that could spawn this question. We'd like to solve your *real* problem, whatever that is, but right now you're asking about the *step* instead of the *goal*. Ask us how to reach your *goal*, not how to perform your notion of a step for it. [Ask smart questions](http://www.catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html).

Comment: @GMan: I'm very sorry if my questions are very blur. Actually my english writing is very poor. But anyway, Ill try to rewrite my whole question so that I can write my goal. Thanks

Comment: @sasayins: No problem. Your English isn't too bad, by the way. Just tell us what your grand idea is, and we'll help you get there. It may or may not include the step "get the address of the end of the heap".

Answer (score 4):

You would have to at least specify what platform you're dealing with, and realize on many platforms the question doesn't really have an answer. The 'heap' doesn't need to be contiguous - in many cases there will be several heaps for different types of objects (like for certain sized requests), and the runtime might acquire blocks for the 'heap' as needed from the underlying OS.

Similarly for the 'program' - various parts of the executable might be interspersed with data, or regions of address space that have nothing in them.

Comment: So I guess its impossible to determine the address of the heap and calculate the size of the heap.

Comment: @sasayins: it might be possible depending on your platform.  Since you're using an `asm` block, I assume portability isn't of much importance to you.

Answer (score 3):

Assembly is **utterly useless** for this. If your system's implementation of the standard library exposes a variable that stores the address of the top of the heap, you can access it just as easily without asm. Otherwise, you might be able to access and process OS-specific process data, for instance (on Linux) `/proc/self/smaps`, to determine your program's address layout. But regardless, **asm will not help you**.

Comment: I hope there is an implementation to know the size of the heap.

Comment: Explain what you're trying to achieve, what you mean to include as "heap", and what OS you're on. Otherwise there is no way to help you since the concept of a "heap" is implementation-specific.

Comment: @R: I'm in Linux OS. I really want to know how can I know the size of the heap used of my application. Edited question thanks.

Comment: Open `/proc/self/maps` and process the line that ends in `[heap]`. Note that this will only show memory obtained by `brk`. If `malloc` uses `mmap` to service large requests, they will be separate anonymous mappings (no name at the end of the line). The first 2 (hex) numbers on each line are the start and end addresses for the mapping, so you can use them to determine the size.

Comment: @R: i tried to read the /proc/self/maps and tried to allocate before and after the reading the file but didn't gave me different results.

Comment: The heap size has at least 4k (page) granularity, and maybe worse depending on the `malloc` implementation in use. You'll have to allocate more than a few bytes to see a difference.

Answer (score 2):

If your standard library is glibc (likely), then you can `#include <malloc.h>` and call `malloc_stats();` to print a heap report to `stderr`.